# Column names: () being replaced by dots when reading csv files

Tags: r, csv

This question might sound silly, anyway, I have a `csv` file with column names like this: `gauge_(1)`, `gauge_(2)` , etc. 
and when I load it using `read.csv()` the names change to `gauge_.1.`, `gauge_.2.`, etc.

I tried using the `quote` argument but couldn't get any good result.

What should I do to keep the names without change? I mean whitout the **( )** characters being changed to **dots**?

Thank you!

Comment: `read.csv(..., check.names = FALSE)` will allow you to keep the original column names. But things like `df$gauge_(1)` won't work, that's why R changes them. I would recommend either letting R change them or changing them yourself to something like `gauge_1`.

Comment: @Marius, post as answer (if you can't find a duplicate, which would be better)?

Comment: Like @Marius mentioned, you can't have names with parenthesis in them. Parenthesis are reserved for functions and having them in the names could really mess things up. You could try the `readr` package which has the `read_csv()` function. It might surround the column names with forward ticks. So the names will become df$`gauge_(1)'. (Note the last ' should be a back tick but this changes the formatting in stack overflow)